# How do i insert data already present in one table into another using Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I have table called Users which already has id of users who are registered.This table is in different database which is named  TrackUsers. Now I am using new database called Terms which has field called ID which should take all ID's from users table and insert into this table.For this i used database first approach.
I am using ASP.NET MVC Entity framework. Below is the code I am using in controller :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private AppMarketplaceEntities db = new AppMarketplaceEntities();
    private InstallTrackerEntities db1 = new InstallTrackerEntities();


   public ActionResult Index()
    {
   List<int> gatewayUserId = new List<int>();

        using (var ctx = new InstallTrackerEntities())
        {
            gatewayUserId = ctx.Gateway_Users.Select(f => f.GatewayuserUID).ToList();
        }
        using (var ctx2 = new AppMarketplaceEntities())
        {
            foreach (var id in gatewayUserId)
            {
                ctx2.AppTerms.Add(new AppTerm() { GatewayuserUID = id });
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View();  
        }

        }
        }
```

But still GatewayUserUID is showing null in Appterms table.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: My mistake.Did changes.

Comment: I would note that you should take t-SQL over the Entity Framework for bulk inserts. If you're inserting a lot of data over, the performance difference could be non-trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 .edmx files (and therefore different dbcontexts for each database), are you looking for something like this?

```
List<int> userids = new List<int>();
using(var ctx = new TrackUsersEntities())
{
    userids = ctx.Users.Select(f => f.UserId).ToList();
}

using(var ctx2 = new OtherDatabaseEntities())
{
    foreach(var id in userids)
    {
        ctx2.Terms.Add(new Term() { ID = id });
    }
    ctx2.SaveChanges();
}
```

As for where to place the code, I'd put it in the Services layer (if it exists), otherwise in the Controller class.

Comment: Hi i have only one database in my MVC that is from Terms.I tried to add another database which has Trackusers table and it is showing some errors in MVC.It is developed by others and it has more files so I cant even work on that error.If you dont mind could you please give me code of how to access trackuser table from SQL server and update in terms table which I have in MVC..

Comment: The easiest way to access your trackuser table is through an .edmx file (see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716703(v=vs.103).aspx) for a guide in creating one from an existing database).

Comment: But I AM getting table doesn't have primary key for every table if i try to use database first approach for trackuser database. But this database is working properly in SQL Server.So what I AM supposed to do now??

Comment: Hi now its not giving error.dont know how. But now I followed your approach and wrote code.But after running also in terms table ID is null.It is not taking ID from Users table. I cant even post my code here since its lenghty. any suggestions?? I wrote ur code in controller like   public ActionResult Index()
        { your logic here } retrun view() } do i need to do anything in view to make this works?

Comment: Use the debugger and check if userids (the list) is empty after the using statement finishes. If it is, post the code you use to get the UserId's. Otherwise, the problem lies in the second part(adding new Terms). Is your Terms table empty? Do you only need to insert UserId's? Do you have a primary key in Terms and auto-increment set on it? NOTE: You can edit your question and append to it, if you have lengthy code.

Comment: Hi I EDITED question.Please have a look into that for code snippet.and yes I have primary key in my Appterm table and it is called termId. Infact when i debugg I can see the ID'S in foreach statement gatewayUserId, but dont know why it is not saving..yes I need only Userid to insert into table.

Comment: Hi just did minor change to your code.that is  instead of db.savechanges(), I wrote, ctx2.savechanges(), and it worked. Appreciate your help..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35768/discussion-between-dev-and-valentin)